# ¿Como pasar un objeto como parámetro en javascript?

Tags: json, variables, objeto

Necesito pasar a esta función `myMapFull('+idSubCategoria+');` este parámetro pero recibo el siguiente error al ejecutar la función:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Si hago un *alert* a `idSubCategoria`, el *alert* me muestra `[objet][objet]`, si le hago el *alert* a `idSubCategoria['0'].name`, me muestra el valor. (por si esto ayuda) `idSubCategoria` es un **Json**. En la funcion `submenuCat` hago  `objJsonSub=JSON.parse(data);` y `objJsonSub` es el valor que le paso.

La función `subMenuCat` es la que me va a devolver el parámeto que pretendo pasar como parámetro.

Si el parámetro pasado es idSubCategoria['0'].id, este se pasa bien, creo que el problema no es que este mal concatenado.

```
function menuCat(){ 
    subMenuCat("",function(idSubCategoria){
            var menuCate='<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
            menuCate+='<li class="dropdown"> <a  onClick=" myMapFull('+idSubCategoria+'); "> <b>Convenios</b></a></li>';
                $.each(idSubCategoria, function(j, subCategoria) { 
                });
            });

        }


    function subMenuCat(idCategoria,callbackFunction){ //Esta funcion me va a devolver las subcategorias de una categoria en un json 
    var parametros = {
            "idCat":idCategoria,
        }
        $.ajax ({
            data: parametros,
            url: "php/AgrApp/cat_cnv.php",
            type: "POST",

        success: function(data){
            objJsonSub=JSON.parse(data);
            callbackFunction(objJsonSub); 
            }   
        });
    }
```

He intentado poner el practica el primer caso del compañero y recibo el error:        `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input  myMapFull([{`

Comment: En donde exactamente te sale el error?

Comment: Como es el valor que el parametro `idSubCategoria` contiene? Un json?

Comment: el resultado es un json:objJsonSub, que es el resultado del Ajax, de JSON.parse(data)

Comment: Error de sintaxis al concatenar. Debería ser: `'<li class="dropdown"> <a onClick=" myMapFull('"+idSubCategoria+"'); "> <b>Convenios</b></a></li>'` si es que `idSubCategoria` es un string.

Comment: Mas sencillo usando [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings): ``<li class="dropdown"> <a onClick=" myMapFull('${idSubCategoria}');">``.

Comment: El primer caso da error: unexpected string, y el segundo caso Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que al ejecutar esta linea
`menuCate+='<li class="dropdown"> <a  onClick=" myMapFull('+idSubCategoria+'); "> <b>Convenios</b></a></li>';`
estas usando el operador + entre un string y un objeto, por lo cual lo que hara sera tratar de convertir idSubCategoria a un string para poder ocncatenarlo, lo cual resultara en un string que contenga `"[Object] [Object]"`.
 Vos lo que querrias seria hacer que la funcion tome ese parametro, esto lo podes obtener de dos formas diferentes:
 Podes hardcodear el objeto en el string, de la siguiente manera:

```
menuCate+='<li class="dropdown"> <a  onClick="myMapFull('+JSON.stringify(idSubCategoria)+'); "> <b>Convenios</b></a></li>';
```

O podes crear una referencia global al objeto y pasarle como parametro esa referencia:

```
window.idSubCategoriaGlobal = idSubCategoria;
menuCate+='<li class="dropdown"> <a  onClick=" myMapFull(idSubCategoriaGlobal); "> <b>Convenios</b></a></li>';
```

En ese caso deberias crear una global diferente por cada subcateogria distinta.

Answer (score 0):

> Para alguien que sea dinámico en js aqui va mi aportación
> Suponiendo que tus datos los traes con ajax

```
 function CargarGrid() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: '/Cupos/ObtenerGrid',
            contentType: "Aplication/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
             
                if (data.request.codigo == "000") {
                    var row = null;
                    $('#Container').show();
                    var html = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                        row = {
                            Id: data.data[i].Id,
                            Idcanal: data.data[i].Idcanal,
                            Nombre: data.data[i].Nombre,
                            Canal: data.data[i].Canal,
                            Descripcion: data.data[i].Descripcion
                        }
                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += "<td><button class='' type='button' onclick='Seleccion(" + JSON.stringify(row) + ")'><img src='../../Imagenes/Botones/seleccionar.gif' /></button></td>";
                        html += "<td><button onclick='deleteService(" + data.data[i].Id + ")' type='button'><img src='../../Imagenes/Botones/eliminar.gif' /></button></td>";
                        html += "<td>" + data.data[i].Idcanal + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + data.data[i].Nombre + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + data.data[i].Canal + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + data.data[i].Descripcion + "</td>";
                        html += "</tr>";
                    }                        
                    $('#bodytable').html(html);
                } else {
                    $('#MensajeToltip').val(data.data.mensaje);
                    $('#Container').hide();
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

> Entonces al seleccionar la fila obtienes las propiedades que desees así

```
 function Seleccion(data) {                    
        var Id = data.Id;
        var Nombre=data.Nombre;
        // tu demas atributos



    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function subMenuCat(idCategoria){  
    var parametros = {
            "idCat":idCategoria,
        }
        $.ajax ({
            data: parametros,
            url: "php/AgrApp/cat_cnv.php",
            type: "POST",

        success: function(data){

            objJsonSub=JSON.parse(data);
           //recorres tu objJsonSub para mostrar tu Menu
           // ....
                var objJsonSub = {
           "p1": "value1",
          "p2": "value2",
          "p3": "value3"
          };

       for (var key in objJsonSub) {
          if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             console.log(key + " -> " + objJsonSub[key]);
          }
       }


            }   
        });
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, intenta poner explicaciones al código. Una respuesta que solo incluye código se considera de 'baja' calidad.